# Magento 2 Sign Static Files Showing CSS/JS 404 Error in SEO Reports

Tags: magento2, seo, robots.txt

I am using Version Number In File Paths in Magento 2, but it's showing 404 errors in SEO reports after run Magento deploy command because of deploy command change version number every time

I have also added below code in Robots.txt file

```
`Disallow: /pub/static/`
```

But still, it's showing in 404 errors in SEO reports. I can't disable Sign static files function from the admin side.

Please let me know how can we solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with my robots.txt, At the end of the file I have allowed all folder for a crawler.